# How to change style of TextView to Bold with someTextView.getTypeface().getStyle()?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview, font-face

I would like to implement a button that will add/remove boldness of font according to the state of the font before the change. So far I have come up with this:

```
boldFont.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    int currentTypeface = centerTextView.getTypeface().getStyle();
    if (currentTypeface == Typeface.ITALIC ) centerTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
    else if (currentTypeface == Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC ) centerTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
    else centerTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
  }
});
```

but I receive `NullPointerException` on the line where I assign `int currentTypeface = centerTextView.getTypeface().getStyle();`.

I do not assign the style before that piece of code.

Do I have to ?

**EDIT**

Having this I cannot assign a new `Typeface` to `TextView`

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Typeface currentTypeface = centerTextView.getTypeface();
    if (currentTypeface != null) {
      int currentStyle = currentTypeface.getStyle();
      if (currentStyle == Typeface.ITALIC ) centerTextView.setTypeface(currentTypeface, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
      else if (currentStyle == Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC ) centerTextView.setTypeface(currentTypeface, Typeface.ITALIC);
      else centerTextView.setTypeface(currentTypeface, Typeface.BOLD);         
    }
    else{
      // WHAT HERE ?
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify Style:

```
if(yourTextViewInstance.getTypeface() != null){
   if(yourTextViewInstance.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD ){
      //do your stuff
   }else{
     //do other stuff
   }
}
```

Set Bold:

```
yourTextViewInstance.setTypeface(yourTextViewInstance.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: Ok but if current Typeface is null then how can I access current style  (to check if the text is bold or italic at the moment of verification) ?

Comment: If is null you don't have typeface and style yet =)

Comment: // what here

centerTextView.setTypeface(centerTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);

Comment: Yes but how do I create it? I can put your second piece of code there but then I still do not assign a `Typeface` and still cannot get the style.

Comment: Create? When you user setTypeface(etc...) the style is created

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with setting `null` as first parameter to `setTypeface` when I changed to :

```
centerTextView.setTypeface(currentTypeface, Typeface.BOLD);
```

it's ok now.